# How set font color in php after a character

Tags: php

I have a string selected from database, and I want to change the font color of string after a '<', then back to initial color after '>'. Example:  `rowselected= abcd<efgh>lmno`

How can I change the color of efgh?

I tried with

```
<?php between ('<', '>', rowselected) echo '<span style="color:red;">' . rowselected . '</span>' ?>
```

obviusly not work, but i'm searching a solution like this

Comment: PHP doesn’t have any `between` function or operator - so I think this hardly qualifies as an actual attempt on your end, because it is basically just pseudo code / wishful thinking. Go look into string functions and/or regular expressions, and try something that actually makes a bit of sense at least. We can discuss any halfway serious attempts here - but so far, IMHO this isn’t even one.

Answer (score 1):

A solution using a regex to get the matches on the string and then replace them:

```
$str = 'abcd<efgh>lmno';

preg_match_all('/<[\S]*?>/m', $str, $matches, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);

$replacements = $needles = [];
foreach ($matches[0] as $match) {
    $needles[]      = $match;
    $replacements[] = '<span style="color:red;">' . $match . '</span>';
}

echo str_replace($needles, $replacements, $str);
```

Result: `abcd<span style="color:red;"><efgh></span>lmno`

Comment: result : abcdlmno

Comment: @albreik check this http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/bbe6272ec2ddc7c2116de90f0b3f9d3f7421db35

Comment: Yes, but on wampserver (php v. 7.2.18) the result is that. The substring between < > is hidden. The same result on w3S server.

Comment: @albreik what's the result of `print_r($matches);`?

Comment: `Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => ) )`

Comment: @albreik The regex is not matching your string. Can you post the string obtained from the DB?

Comment: The string is `$str = 'abcd<efgh>lmno';` I've not tried with database yet

Answer (score 0):

You can simply apply `str_replace` for `<>` sign. Like this way

```
$rowselected = 'abcd<efgh>lmno';

$rowselected = str_replace('<', '<<span style="color:red">', $rowselected);
$rowselected = str_replace('>', '</span>>', $row);

// result
// "abcd<<span style="color:red"</span>>efgh</span>>lmno"
```